# In android app how do I display information in a table that is associated with info from another table?

Tags: android, mysql, foreign-keys

I'm trying to make my android app display a list of book titles associated with a specified writer, or username. I've found very little pages or videos on the internet, using terms like 'mysql foreign key' Maybe I'm searching the wrong thing.

What I'm trying to do: here are the usernames in my database, displayed in Phpmyadmin.

[image]

So 'John Grisham' logs into my app and I use this code to check he is in my database, which works fine :

```
 @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String username = etUsername.getText().toString();

                Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                            boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                            if (success) {
                                String username = jsonResponse.getString("username");

                                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, UserAreaActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("username", username);

                                LoginActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
```

In the subsequent activity I have something like :

```
String message = username + ", here are your book titles :";
        welcomeMessage.setText(message);
```

which would give, if John Grisham logs in, 'John Grisham, here are your book titles :'

But how do I show the book titles? What code would I use?

Here is my book titles table:

[image]

user_id, the author of the books, is the foreign key of the book titles table...if that makes sense.

Here's the php script I use to connect to my database:

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "password", "databasename");

$username = $_POST["username"];

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?");

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "s", $username);

mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);

mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $user_id, $username);

$response["success"] = false;  

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){

$response["success"] = true;  

$response["username"] = $username;

echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

Comment: This would be a lot less clunky and verbose on the PHP side using the object-oriented `mysqli` interface. Also in dire need of some indentation.

Answer (score 0):

Are the booktitles contained within the same JSON response as the author's name?

You wrote `String username = jsonResponse.getString("username");`

Set a breakpoint there and check if the jsonResponse object also contains any fields for the book titles of the author.

Comment: Sorry, but don't understand what you mean. I don't have any reference to book titles in my code (yet), it is merely a table in the database that my app connects to with php. I'm editing my question and putting in my php script, if that's any help.